# how can i store in two index using two JSON formated log files using filebeat and output to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, filebeat

below is my configuration file for filebeat which is present in /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml,
it throws an error of

> Failed to publish events: temporary bulk send failure

```
filebeat.prospectors:
  - paths:
     - /var/log/nginx/virus123.log
   input_type: log
   fields:
      type:virus123
   json.keys_under_root: true


   - paths:
     - /var/log/nginx/virus1234.log
     input_type: log
     fields:
       type:virus1234
     json.keys_under_root: true

setup.template.name: "filebeat-%{[beat.version]}"
setup.template.pattern: "filebeat-%{[beat.version]}-*"
setup.template.overwrite: true

processors:
 - drop_fields:
     fields: ["beat","source"]


output.elasticsearch:
  index: index: "filebeat-%{[beat.version]}-%{[fields.type]:other}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"

  hosts: ["http://127.0.0.1:9200"]
```

Comment: what version of Filebeat are you using?

Comment: Also, normally the bulk sense failure is caused by an error on the Elasticsearch side. Knowing which error elasticsearch returns could be helpful here.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found your problem, Although i'm not sure it is the only problem

```
index: index: "filebeat-%{[beat.version]}-%{[fields.type]:other}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
```

should be:

```
index: "filebeat-%{[beat.version]}-%{[fields.type]:other}-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
```

I saw a similar problem with a wrong index which cause the same error that you showed

Comment: that was a typo mistake it's not working solution, I go with logagent
it's super awesome and lightweight as compared to logstash